# get warning message when a user enters invalid item in a combo box

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a combo box in a user form. It contains a list of items (dates) in the dropdown. But the user can also enter an item. If the entry matches with the combo box list items (which is in an excel sheet) then it should allow, otherwise it should give a warning message "invalid entry".

Right now, as soon as I enter a number, I get a run time error (run time error 13, type mismatch). How do I replace the runtime error with a user friendly message box.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Dim sl As Double
    Dim by As Double
    Dim lrange As Range
    Set lrange = Workbooks("abc").Worksheets("TL-USD").Range("O2") 

    lrange.Value = ComboBox1.Value

    sl = Workbooks("abc").Worksheets("TL-USD").Range("P2").Value ~~getting error here~~
    by = Workbooks("abc").Worksheets("TL-USD").Range("Q2").Value


    Sell.Caption = "Sell 1 $ in " & sl & " TL"
    Buy.Caption = "Buy 1 $ in " & by & " TL"

End Sub
```

The cell P2 & Q2 has vlookup formula to pull the relevant rates for that date from the table in the sheet. Is there a way to check in the date column with the date that is entered by the user and if it matches with any of the dates then allow to enter otherwise give out a message.

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that `Workbooks("abc").Worksheets("TL-USD").Range("P2").Value` is not a string? This would mean that a string cannot be converted in a `Double` as `sl` variable is declared... If you need a double, you must check if the range in discussion is the appropriate one. If you need a string, you must change `Dim sl As String` or  `Dim sl As Variant`, which allows a larger aria of evaluation...

Comment: Or is there a formula in the range `Workbooks("abc").Worksheets("TL-USD").Range("P2")` which  is calculated according to `lrange.Value`?

Comment: Your last question may receive an appropriate answer only if you tell/show us the range (Date column) where the input to be checked. Otherwise, the answer would be: Yes! :)

Comment: yes, P2 and Q2 contains vlookup formulas. I have added an image of the sheet.

Comment: In which column should the code search in order to validate the combo entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not asked my question related to the column where the validation must be done... The next code works with the assumption that the column in discussion is B:B. If not, please adapt the code for the appropriate column. It validate the input by checking existence of the `ComboBox1.Value` in the respective range:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim shTL As Worksheet, sl As Double, by As Double, rngSearch As Range
    Dim lrange As Range, lastRow As Long

    Set shTL = ActiveSheet ' Workbooks("abc").Worksheets("TL-USD")
    Set lrange = shTL.Range("O2")
    lastRow = shTL.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Set rngSearch = shTL.Range("B2:B" & lastRow)

     'validate the combo entry:
     If IsValid(CDbl(ComboBox1.Value), rngSearch) Then
        lrange.Value = ComboBox1.Value
     Else
        MsgBox "The enered value in Combo (""" & ComboBox1.Value & _
                """) could not be found in range """ & rngSearch.address & """."
        Exit Sub
     End If

    sl = shTL.Range("P2").Value ' ~~ Not getting error here (I hope...)~~
    by = shTL.Range("Q2").Value


    Sell.Caption = "Sell 1 $ in " & sl & " TL"
    Buy.Caption = "Buy 1 $ in " & by & " TL"
End Sub

Function IsValid(strSearch As Double, rngSearch As Range) As Boolean
   Dim c As Range
   For Each c In rngSearch
        If CDbl(c.Value) = strSearch Then IsValid = True: Exit Function
   Next
End Function
```

Comment: thank you so much. I was able to use the code you provided with a few modifications.

Comment: Glad I could help! Wgat modifications were necessary?

Comment: strSearch variable needed to be date type and not double, since we were looking for dates in the A column to match. If the search range was column B then double would have been correct. And I removed the CDbl function since it was not required.

Comment: I couldn't know all that, since the variable was declared as Double. I just supposed that the column to be processed could be B:B or D:D... But, glad you could find a way to make it working for your purpose.